# How can I change the indent of the row numbers in my tabular environment?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm using tabular to align numbers, answer choices basically.  Each row is numbered (A), (B), etc. Is there any way to decrease the space between the row label and the first column?

```
\newcounter{ans}
\renewcommand\theans{\Alph{ans}}
\newcommand\anslabel{(\theans)}

\setcounter{ans}{0}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\stepcounter{ans}(\theans)}lrr@{.}l}
&$-2$ \\
&$-1$ \\
&$0.8$ \\
&$1$ \\
&$2.3$ \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: change `lrr` to `l@{\hspace{0cm}}rr`

Comment: why has your table got 4 columns declared but you only use 2?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina thanks (I was in time to correct the comment:-)

Comment: Hm, I tried your suggestion and it gives me the erorr ! Use of \@@array doesn't match its definition.  I'm using four columns because I'm using the same tabular environment multiple times (some of which need four columns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please always post *complete* documents showing all packages used. Since you are using `array` I also inserted the `$` in the preamble so the second column is math mode. `@{}` removes the default inter column space, and in this example I have replaced it with `\hspace{1pt}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{ans}
\renewcommand\theans{\Alph{ans}}
\newcommand\anslabel{(\theans)}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{ans}{0}
\begin{tabular}{
@{}>{\stepcounter{ans}(\theans)}l
@{\hspace{1pt}}>{$}r<{$}
r@{.}l
}
&-2 \\
&-1 \\
&0.8 \\
&1 \\
&2.3
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```